# Wiping RAM before shutdown, How does Linux allocate memory?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, ram, dd

I know that many people think that wiping the RAM at shutdown is fairly pointless, I've done a fair bit of research on the benefits and drawbacks (and if it is really worth it). So in the nicest politest possible way... please no comments such as "Why do you want to wipe the Ram, its pointless"

I tried to DD /dev/mem and as expected DD threw up an error and the kernel warned that DD tried to access memory between 101000 and 101200. So my question is... How is memory allocated in Linux and more precisely, would any personal information exist between addresses 101000 and 101200 or is it totally reserved/protected for the kernel?

Thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: Well, the RAM is just volatile so nothing to worry about after the system has shut down.
However, the swap partitions/files may still contain some information depending on your system config.

Comment: Sorry I should probably add that i'm running a custom live distribution so no swap space.

Comment: Then what's to worry about? Why do you want to wipe RAM? Make sure the machine is powered off longer than perhaps 10s and it should be safe.

Comment: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, please read my question. I really don't want to get into a debate on whether its worth doing or not.

Comment: I did read your question and still the point remains valid even if you want to avoid the debate. Do you think the contents are going to be stored in hyperspace and then somehow warped back into existence when power comes back? We're talking about RAM, not flash right? Trying to `dd` your `/dev/kmem` (as root) will at best get you a nice crash and at worst corrupt some data on persistent storage in the process.

Comment: My question is .. How is memory allocated in Linux and more precisely, would any personal information exist between addresses 101000 and 101200 or is it totally reserved/protected for the kernel? A debate on wiping RAM is not important or useful, I put it there for context.

Comment: then be specific or remove the misleading part from your question. How is it allocated a.) in user mode, b.) in kernel mode, c.) in user mode with library xyz. Because in user mode this is quite specific to the library and you will find numerous implementations of optimized allocators for various uses. Read up on `sbrk` and `brk` functions for starters.

Comment: OK, what part do you find misleading and I will remove it. A few more specifics.. I have been tasked with building an 'over the top' operating system for the paranoid... personally, i know that the contents of RAM degrades after power is lost (unless quickly frozen). However i'm trying to create a wipe script to be run if a user is pulled kicking and screaming from the PC (so no power is lost), or if the RAM has been hooked up to a backup power source (I know this is very unlikely). Applications are run in usermode with no library's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you provided no details I am assuming you are using quite recent kernel version running on x86.

[Linux documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/x86/boot.txt) provides physical memory layout after boot. You can see there that kernel is loaded at address 0x100000. That means in the region you are asking about (0x101000 - 0x101200) there is only kernel code.

Physical memory is allocated in pages using binary buddy allocator. It is described in much more details [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html).

However, wiping physical memory using anything except kernel code is impossible and may be dangerous (corruption of data on disks). If you really want to wipe RAM at shutdown I would suggest hacking the kernel.

Comment: Wrote that (about wiping dangerous) already in the comments, but +1 for the links. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to wipe physical memory *to the best of your ability* (you mentioned `dd` so we are talking about an userland solution!), it is sufficient to create an anonymous mapping the same size as the installed RAM<sup>1</sup> and to touch every page by writing a single byte (or any other amount) to one address inside each page.

This will cause a page fault and trigger a copy-on-write operation on the zero page for every page in your mapping that you touch, which will either commit an already zeroed page or zero an unused non-zeroed physical page of memory -- until there are none left, at which point your process will be killed by the OOM killer (or will receive `SIGBUS`, depending which one hits your process first).
If you want it to be somewhat "cleaner" (that is, without OOM killer), you need to stop before touching the last page, obviously. But in general, this is all it takes.

You will **not** be able to wipe all physical pages like this, but there really is no way of doing that with a user process (not without swap, and not in a *deterministic* way).
Pages that are committed by other processes or pages that belong to the kernel can't be overwritten with this approach, at least not *reliably* (since there is no swap, these can't be swapped out, though you might be lucky and have OOM kill other processes instead of yours).
You cannot in general overwrite physical memory in a 100% reliable way unless you replace the running kernel.

If you want to be super "thorough", then your only option is to write code as it can be found e.g. in memtest_x86, which you invoke from kernel mode, replace the running kernel and overwrite raw physical memory "the hard way", much like memtest_x86 does, too.

But then, if you go the ultra-paranoia route, don't forget to clear GPU memory and wipe hard disk caches and network card memory as well...

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, you would have to create a mapping the size of the maximum commit size -- but you stated that there is no swap, so "size of RAM" will do. Seeing how modern disk drives do extensive wear-levelling, overwriting swap wouldn't help an awful lot anyway, but at least you could guarantee that you are hitting all RAM pages if you commit up to the maximum commit size.